# DjangoのDEBUG=False時に一部の画面が表示されなくなる

Tags: python, django

### 原因は環境変数に格納しているSECRETKEYなどが取得できていないためのようです。

次のように書くと動きます。

```
SECRET_KEY = '!55適当j%'
```

次のように書き変えると動きません。

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

idle で `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` を投入すると値を取得してきます。
そのため環境変数への設定は問題ないと思います。
settings.py には `import os` を記載しています。

### 試したこと

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

↓

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

動かず

### DEBUG = Falseにする前の設定等

・settings.pyへの変更

```
STATIC_ROOT = "C:/Users/username/projectname/static"
DEBUG=False
```

・コマンド

```sh
python manage.py collectstatic
```

環境変数の取得方法がDEBUG=Falseになると変わるのでしょうか。
ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/277328

Comment: 問題はなんでしょうか？”DjangoのDEBUG=False時に一部の画面が表示されなくなる”か、それとも”SECRET_KEYを環境変数でわたせない”？後者のほうですかね？

Comment: DjangoのDEBUG=False時にSECRET_KEYを環境変数でわたせなくなってしまうので、これを渡せるようにしたい、というのが正確なところです。よろしくお願いします。